# Debug xv6 on mac with CLion

Tags: macos, gdb, clion, xv6

I've looked through the internet and searched for solution for debugging xv6 on mac with CLion and didn't find one. as you know it's difficult (or maybe impossible, I didn't succeeded anyway) to make gdb work on macOS.
So, how can I do it? How can I debug xv6 with CLion on macOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run `make qemu-gdb clean` in terminal (in the project's directory of course), pay attention for the port, it may be different for some reason, for me it was 25501.
All I needed to do is the following:[image: The image]
`kernel` is good for debugging `proc.c`, if you want to debug other file, (i.e. `sh.c`) you should put `_sh` instead.

Answer (score 4):

**NOTE** that in order to be able to debug [xv6-riscv](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-riscv) you will need to use `riscv64-unknown-elf-gdb` instead of `gdb`

as following:
[image]